# .NET using WebDriver.FindElement().Text after SelectElement option click doesn't update "data"

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

on my web page I have a select element that update the page content after clicking on it.

I write a piece of code that allow me to navigate threw the different options of the select element.
This part of the code work well but, after those line, when I try to get some "data" using

`WebDriver.FindElement().Text` (with the proper XPath of course)

in the loop that allow me to navigate threw options, it seems that the data doesn't properly update on the page.

Here is the snippet I wrote :

```
foreach(IWebElement option in optionList)
             {
                option.Click();

                var productName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1/span"));
                var productPrice = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[1]/meta"));
                var productDescription = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[5]"));
                var productReference = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span"));
                var productReferer = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a"));

                ProductReference pr = new()
                {
                    DisplayName = productName.Text,
                    Price = productPrice.Text,
                    Description = productDescription.Text,
                    Referer = productReferer.Text,
                    Reference = productReference.Text,
                    AttributName = "Couleurs",
                    AttributValue = option.Text,
                };
                products.Add(pr);

                Console.WriteLine(pr);
            }
```

I don't if there is a way to "Refresh" the browser or anything else.

pr AttributValue is always correct but, for example, the reference is already the same whereas it should be different.

Thank for futur help !

**MORE INFORMATIONS :**

Here is the code that come before the loop :

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless=new");
            chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

            IWebElement colorChoiceElmt = driver.FindElement(By.Id("group_4"));

            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(colorChoiceElmt);
            IList<IWebElement> optionList = select.Options;
```

**ALREADY TESTED CODE :**

-- RAMON SUGGESTION --

I tried this after Ramon suggestion. Thing is that on Selenium docs, they ask us to not use **ExpectedConditions** (and it create an error by using it) so I followed they recommendations and use Explicit wait like this :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                wait.Until(d => colorChoiceElmt.Displayed);
                colorChoiceElmt.SendKeys("Displayed");
```

-- YAROSLAVM SUGGESTION --

Because ExpectedConditions is not yet supported by Selenium in them lastest version I installed "SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers" nugget package to the followed code to work. Spoiler, result is the same.

```
static void ProcessUrl(string url)
        {
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless=new");
            chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
            ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            IWebElement colorChoiceElmt = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("group_4")));

            SelectElement select = new SelectElement(colorChoiceElmt);
            IList<IWebElement> optionList = select.Options;
            string currentProductReference = null;

            for (int index = 0; index < optionList.Count; index++)
            {
                if (index > 1)
                {
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.StalenessOf(colorChoiceElmt));
                }

                colorChoiceElmt = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("group_4")));
                select = new SelectElement(colorChoiceElmt);
                optionList = select.Options;
                select.SelectByIndex(index);
                IWebElement product = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-info-row"));
                IWebElement productName = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=name]"));
                IWebElement productPrice = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-price"));
                IWebElement productDescription = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".product-description p"))[4];
                IWebElement productReference = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=sku]"));
                currentProductReference = productReference.Text;
                IWebElement productReferer = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product_header_container a"));

                ProductReference pr = new()
                {
                    DisplayName = productName.Text,
                    Price = productPrice.Text,
                    Description = productDescription.Text,
                    Referer = productReferer.Text,
                    Reference = productReference.Text,
                    AttributName = "Couleurs",
                    AttributValue = optionList[index].Text,
                };
                products.Add(pr);

                Console.WriteLine(pr);
            }

            driver.Quit();
        }
```

Comment: Without resource it's quite difficult to help you. Please, provide minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Now, you can see all the code before the loop that I describe before. Hope this can help you understand. @Yaroslavm

Comment: I need just `url` variable, without it code can't be debugged

Comment: [Here it is](https://www.wrs.it/fr/bouchon-de-huile-moteur/200579-too02-bouchon-de-remplissage-d-huile-ducabike-ducati-diavel-2011.html) @Yaroslavm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all - don't use absolute selectors.
Try to use unique and short selectors that point to needed element.

Then - after selecting dropdown option on 2+ try you should wait for previous dropdown element be re-rendered (it happens in your case), so when it happened - new product card info is shown.
Then you just re-init dropdown element and get data from the next loop.

I added general code with described logic, you can adjust it and adopt to your script structure.

Waiting for element visbility, using `4.0+` `WebDriverWait` would be something like

```bash
IWebElement colorChoiceElmt = wait.Until(webDriver =>
        {
            IWebElement target = driver.FindElement(By.Id("group_4"));
            return target.Displayed ? target : null;
        });
```

Waiting for element to be stale similar to

```bash
wait.Until(webDriver =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IWebElement target = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=image]"));
                        return !target.Displayed
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

So, working example is:

```bash
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        { 
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("disable-popup-blocking");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless=new");

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        string url = "https://www.wrs.it/fr/bouchon-de-huile-moteur/200579-too02-bouchon-de-remplissage-d-huile-ducabike-ducati-diavel-2011.html";
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement colorChoiceElmt = wait.Until(webDriver =>
        {
            IWebElement target = driver.FindElement(By.Id("group_4"));
            return target.Displayed ? target : null;
        });

        SelectElement select = new SelectElement(colorChoiceElmt);
        IList<IWebElement> optionList = select.Options;

        List<Dictionary<string, string>> products = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        IWebElement product = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-info-row"));
        string imageHref = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=image]")).GetDomProperty("href");
        string referenceText = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=sku]")).Text;
        for (int index = 0; index < optionList.Count; index++)
        {
            select.SelectByIndex(index);
            wait.Until(webDriver =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IWebElement target = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=image]"));
                        return !target.GetDomProperty("href").Equals(imageHref);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            wait.Until(webDriver =>
            {
                try
                {
                    IWebElement target = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=sku]"));
                    return !target.Text.Equals(referenceText);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            imageHref = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=image]")).GetDomProperty("href");
            product = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-info-row"));
            colorChoiceElmt = wait.Until(webDriver =>
            {
                IWebElement target = driver.FindElement(By.Id("group_4"));
                return target.Displayed ? target : null;
            });
            select = new SelectElement(colorChoiceElmt);
            optionList = select.Options;
            
            string productName = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=name]")).Text;
            string productPrice = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product-price")).Text;
            string productDescription = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".product-description p"))[4].Text;
            referenceText = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[itemprop=sku]")).Text;
            string productReferer = product.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".product_header_container a")).Text;

            Dictionary<string, string> pr = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "DisplayName", productName },
                { "Price", productPrice },
                { "Description", productDescription },
                { "Referer", productReferer },
                { "Reference", referenceText },
                { "AttributName", "Couleurs" },
                { "AttributValue", optionList[index].Text },
            };
            products.Add(pr);
        }

        driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answers to Ramon, ExpectedConditions isn't working on my version of Selenium. As it describe in them website, they invite us to use Explicit Wait. Can you tell me on what version of the selenium nugget package you get this to work ?

Comment: Is because the url change each time you select another option in the selector that we can't get this to work ? Did the "Reference" of the product in your code change for each option ?

Comment: @Thomas_Lcp updated snippet to your version of Selenium

Comment: Thanks for your time @Yaroslavm. I just removed all the code related to "imageHref" because it generate some error but without this, it work like a charm !

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue you're facing is related to the timing of retrieving the elements after clicking on the options in the select element. WebDriver may be trying to fetch the elements before the page has fully updated.

To address this, you can introduce a wait mechanism to ensure that WebDriver waits for the elements to be present and visible before attempting to retrieve their values. Here's an example using `WebDriverWait`:

```cs
foreach (IWebElement option in optionList)
{
    option.Click();

    // Introduce WebDriverWait to wait for the elements to be present
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    var productName = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1/span")));
    var productPrice = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/span[1]/meta")));
    var productDescription = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/p[5]")));
    var productReference = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span")));
    var productReferer = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("/html/body/main/section/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a")));

    // Rest of your code
}
```

This way, WebDriver will wait for a maximum of 10 seconds (you can adjust the timeout as needed) for the elements to be visible before attempting to retrieve their values.

Additionally, you might want to consider using more concise XPath expressions or other locator strategies to make your code more maintainable.

Comment: I tried you code but, as [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/expected_conditions/) says and because I use the last version of it, I should consider using [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-waits). I looked at the code they provide and try the same thing but cannot get it to work because "OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable" I tryed on my select "wich is interactable" but change nothing to the result

Comment: I think this answer is probably an untested copy-paste from ChatGPT